# Giving Borders to the dynamically added HTML table

Tags: c#, html, stylesheet

I have a HTML table added dynamically in my Code behind.

I am able to give the entire table a border.

How can I do this for each row? I want to add a border under each row.

How can I add a hyperlink to cells at runtime?

What I have tried is

```
tdr.Width = "100px";
tdr.Attributes.Add("class", "float-left");

row = new HtmlTableRow(); 
cell = new HtmlTableCell();
cell.InnerText = doc;
row.Cells.Add(cell);
tdr.Rows.Add(row);

row = new HtmlTableRow(); 
cell = new HtmlTableCell();
cell.InnerText = "No Timming";
row.Cells.Add(cell);
tdr.Rows.Add(row);

row = new HtmlTableRow(); 
cell = new HtmlTableCell();
cell.InnerText = weekday[i];
row.Cells.Add(cell);
tdr.Rows.Add(row);
```

And my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .float-left
    {
        float:left;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:2px;
        border-color:Black;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a css on your TR (row)

or an inline border like this:

```
 row.Attributes.Add("border-bottom", "solid red 1px");
```

Comment: The attribute is getting added but no effect in the design of the table Then how to add hyperlink to the value of the cells

Comment: I am using `cell.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "#FF0000");` and it results as `<td style="color; #FF0000;...">...</td>`

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question, you can add the borders without changing your markup generation by adding a simple css rule:

```
tr {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

There is an overview about styling tables in general via both [about.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/ht/how-to-add-internal-lines-in-a-table-with-CSS.htm) and [w3c schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)

Note that you'll also need to set the `border-collapse: collapse;` css attribute on the table.

I've put an [example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y49rf/1/) up for you.

You can place the CSS rule in your CSS section (note I've also added the `border-collapse`):

```
<style type="text/css">

    tr {
      border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    } 

    .float-left{
        float:left;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:2px;
        border-color:Black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

</style>
```

You could also consider removing the float-left css attribute and just change `.float-left` to be `table`  to further simplify your code.

For the second part of your question:

> > and add a hyperlink to each of the values in the table at run time

You can simply use the [HtmlAnchorClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

In effect, a simple example is:

```
HtmlAnchor htmlanchor = new HtmlAnchor();
htmlanchor.HRef = "http://www.linkurl.com";
htmlanchor.InnerText = "My Link Text";
//Add it to a cell
cell.Controls.Add(htmlanchor);
```

This will add a hyperlink to your cell.

You may also want to consider using the [ASP Repeater Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) or the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) control as each of these give you the option to template your markup.

Comment: @user2177370 No problems; hope my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

@Moondust is correct but he's missing the Style tag which is why there is no effect. And besides, you cannot set style on a `<tr>` element. You have to set it on the `<td>`.

ie

The `<tr>` style here does nothing. The `<td>` does!

```
<tr style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:thin;">
  <td width="100px" style="border-bottom: black thin solid;">Boarder</td>
  <td style="background-color:#FFFF00;" width="10px"></td>
</tr>
```

To achieve a bottom border, at least in the cell, it's...

```
row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("style", "border-bottom: black thin solid;");
```

So to do it for a row, you have to do it for each cell. Sorry